# Conditionally set an attribute on an element with JSP Documents (JSPX)

Tags: jsp, xhtml, webforms, jspx

In HTML forms, buttons can be disabled by defining the "disabled" attribute on them, with any value:

```
<button name="btn1" disabled="disabled">Hello</button>
```

If a button is to be enabled, the attribute should not exist as there is no defined value that the disabled attribute can be set to that would leave the button enabled.

This is causing me problems when I want to enable / disable buttons when using JSP Documents (jspx). As JSP documents have to be well-formed XML documents, I can't see any way of conditionally including this attribute, as something like the following isn't legal:

```
<button name="btn1" <%= (isDisabled) ? "disabled" : "" %/> >Hello</button>
```

While I could replicate the tag twice using a JSTL if tag to get the desired effect, in my specific case I have over 15 attributes declared on the button (lots of javascript event handler attributes for AJAX) so duplicating the tag is going to make the JSP very messy.

How can I solve this problem, without sacrificing the readability of the JSP? Are there any custom tags that can add attributes to the parent by manipulating the output DOM?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use a custom JSP tag with dynamic attributes. You use it like this:

```
<util:element elementName="button" name="btn1" disabled="$(isDisabled ? 'disabled' : '')"/>
```

Basically, what this tag does is generate an XML element with elementName and puts all attributes present in the tag, but skips the empty ones.

The tag itself is pretty easy to implement, my implementation is just 44 lines long.

Comment: Could you post the code for this?  I think it would be very instructive.

Comment: This looks like it's going to be the best answer I'll get, it's a shame there's no way to do this with a valid XML syntax without having to write custom tags however...

Comment: If you look at the JSP2X tool, it drops tags for <jspx:element>, <jspx:attribute>, and <jspx:body> (for the body of the element).  That's another alternative that can be used with more complex constructions.

Comment: great solution to use the ternary operator. down some my example.

Answer (score 7):

@alex
great solution to use the ternary operator. I add some of my example, that thanks to you, I just changed the result of the condition, if true, writes the attribute, otherwise not write anything

to populate the list and select the value used, avoiding c:if

```
<select id="selectLang" name="selectLang" >
<c:forEach var="language" items="${alLanguages}" >
    <option value="${language.id}" ${language.code == usedLanguage ? 'selected' : ''} >${language.description}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

to check at start a radio button to avoiding c:if:

```
<input type="radio" id="id0" value="0" name="radio" ${modelVar == 0 ? 'checked' : ''} />
<input type="radio" id="id1" value="1" name="radio" ${modelVar == 1 ? 'checked' : ''} />
<input type="radio" id="id2" value="2" name="radio" ${modelVar == 2 ? 'checked' : ''} />
```

Comment: can `language.code == usedLanguage` can be changed to check `language.code` exist in some list?I want to check something like: `someList.contains(language.code)`, but it fails.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `<jsp:text>` tag to solve this problem using valid XML:

```
<jsp:text><![CDATA[<button name="btn1"]]></jsp:text>
    <c:if test="${isDisabled}"> disabled="disabled"</c:if>
    >
    Hello!
<jsp:text><![CDATA[</button>]]></jsp:text>
```

This is obviously more verbose than some other solutions. But it's **completely self-contained**: no custom tags required. Also, it **scales easily** to as many attributes as you need.

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment saying why. That gives me the opportunity to improve the answer.

Comment: So many downvotes on this answer, but nobody is actually saying why. :-(

Comment: I don't know why someone has downvoted this answer but I feel this is the best approach which suits me.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this approach makes the JSP itself harder to read especially if this is repeated over and over and you lose the XML validation with proper tags.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano You're right -- and I have already pointed out the benefits and liabilities of this approach. If readability is important then you should go with a custom tag. The whole question illustrates why using jspx is not a good idea!

Answer (score 4):

i guess some time has passed since the last post on this, but I came up against the exact same problem with `<select><option selected="selected">` tags, i.e. dynamically declaring which option is selected. To solve that one I made a custom tagx; I posted the details over in another [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761479/how-to-output-option-selectedtrue-from-jspx/2353187#2353187)

I came to the conclusion that there is no nice shortcut; EL and JSP expressions can only exist inside XML element attributes (and in body content). So you have to do the following;

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${isDisabled}"><button name="btn1" disabled="disabled">Hello</button></c:when>
    <c:otherwise><button name="btn1">Hello</button></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Using the scriptlet notation won't work for JSP documents (.jspx)

Comment: Ahh but the scriptlet tag will work http://code.google.com/p/jatl/wiki/JSPExample ... One of the reasons I wrote that library (see link).

Answer (score 3):

Reading about an automatic [jsp to jspx converter](http://diaryproducts.net/about/programming_languages/java/convert_jsp_pages_to_jsp_documents_jspx_with_jsp2x) I came across the `<jsp:element>` and `<jsp:attribute>` tags. If I understand that correctly you should be able to do something like

```
<jsp:element name="button">
  <jsp:attribute name="someAttribute">value</jsp:attribute>
</jsp:element>
```

and have the jsp engine output

```
<button someAttribute="value"/>
```

or something like that. The only problem, pointed out in the page above, is that this doesn't seem to work well with conditional constructs. The author of the converter worked around that creating some helper tags, which you can have a look at downloading the source code I guess. Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, that's probably <jspx:element> and so on.  The JSP2X tool writes those as custom tags into your WEB-INF for use in converted JSP files.

Answer (score 2):

Make a tag library (.tagx) then use the scriptlet tag.

See http://code.google.com/p/jatl/wiki/JSPExample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1">
<jsp:directive.page import="com.googlecode.jatl.Html"/>
<jsp:directive.page import="com.evocatus.product.data.AttributeValue"/>
<jsp:directive.page import="com.evocatus.domain.Product"/>

<jsp:scriptlet>
//<![CDATA[
    final Product p = (Product) request.getAttribute("product");
        new Html(out) {{
           for (AttributeValue v : p.summaryAttributeValues()) {
                   p();
                        strong().text(v.getLabel()).end();
                        text(": " + v.getValue());
                   endAll();
           }
        }};
//]]>
</jsp:scriptlet>

</jsp:root>
```

Yeah this is cheating ... but it gets the job done. Plus can you do really nasty complicated recursion for tree structures this way.

I also posted another solution on my blog and gist.github that uses a bunch of tagx libraries: http://adamgent.com/post/8083703288/conditionally-set-an-attribute-on-an-element-with-jspx

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to do it with **pure** JSP is this way:

```
<jsp:element name="button">
  <jsp:attribute name="name">btn1</jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:attribute name="disabled" omit="${not isDisabled}">disabled</jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:body>Hello</jsp:body>
</jsp:element>
```

The key is to use `omit` attribute on `<jsp:attribute>` - if the expression evaluates to `true` then the attribute won't be renreder at all.

Answer (score 0):

The <%= blah %> syntax is not legal XML needed for JSP Documents. You have 2 options:

1. Replace <%= (isDisabled) ? "disabled" : "" %> with <jsp.expression>(isDisabled) ? "disabled" : ""</jsp.expression>
2. Use the Core taglib and EL (make sure isDisabled is put into page scope) like so:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${isDisabled}">"disabled"</c:when>
  <c:otherwise>""</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Where would these tags be placed though? You still wouldn't be able to put them within the attribute section of the button tag, as this would still be invalid XML, and placing them inside the element will just result in some CDATA being added.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been struggling with the same problem. I tried using `<jsp:attribute name="disabled"/>` inside `<c:if>`, but the compiler tries to attach the disabled attribute to the `c:if` element which fails. But I found that this does work (`stripes:submit` is an element for creating a button of type submit in stripes):

```
<stripes:submit name="process" value="Hello">
   <jsp:attribute name="disabled">
       <c:if test="${x == 0}">disabled</disabled>
   </jsp:attribute>
</stripes:submit>
```

It seems that `jsp:attribute` will not create an attribute at all if the body contains only whitespace, so you either get `disabled="disabled"` or nothing at all.

This will only work if you are using some sort of taglib to generate the button, and the tag element must support the disabled attribute (passing it through to the underlying HTML element). You can't use `jsp:attribute` to add an attribute to a raw HTML element.

Comment: doesn't work for me... the attribute is created even when the body of the tag is empty. I guess it depends on the impl of the JSP you're using (i'm using resin 3.0.24)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like https://stackoverflow.com/a/207882/242042 and encapsulated https://stackoverflow.com/a/775295/242042 so that it can be reused as a tag.

```
<%@ tag
  display-name="element"
  pageEncoding="utf-8"
  description="similar to jsp:element with the capability of removing attributes that are blank, additional features depending on the key are documented in the tag."
  trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"
  dynamic-attributes="attrs"
%>
<%@ attribute
  name="tag"
  description="Element tag name.  Used in place of `name` which is a common attribute in HTML"
  required="true"
%>
<%-- key ends with Key, use i18n --%>
<%-- key starts with x-bool- and value is true, add the key attribute, no value  --%>
<%-- key starts with x-nc- for no check and value is empty, add the key attribute, no value  --%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<jsp:text><![CDATA[<]]></jsp:text>
<c:out value="${tag} " />
<c:forEach var="attr" begin="0" items="${attrs}">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test='${fn:endsWith(attr.key, "Key")}'>
      ${attr.key}=<fmt:message key="${attr.value}" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test='${fn:startsWith(attr.key, "x-bool-") && attr.value == "true"}'>
      <c:out value="${fn:substringAfter(attr.key, 'x-bool-')}" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test='${fn:startsWith(attr.key, "x-bool-") && attr.value != "true"}'>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test='${fn:startsWith(attr.key, "x-nc-")}'>
      <c:out value="${fn:substringAfter(attr.key, 'x-nc-')}" />="<c:out value='${attr.value}' />"
    </c:when>
    <c:when test='${not empty attr.value}'>
      <c:out value="${attr.key}" />="<c:out value='${attr.value}' />"
    </c:when>
  </c:choose>
  <c:out value=" " />
</c:forEach>
<jsp:doBody var="bodyText" />
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty fn:trim(bodyText)}">
    <jsp:text><![CDATA[>]]></jsp:text>
      ${bodyText}
    <jsp:text><![CDATA[<]]></jsp:text>
      <c:out value="/${tag}" />
    <jsp:text><![CDATA[>]]></jsp:text>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <jsp:text><![CDATA[/>]]></jsp:text>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

To use it put it in a taglib tagdir.

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="xyz"%>
...
<xyz:element tag="input"
  type="date"
  id="myDate"
  name="myDate"
  x-bool-required="true"
/>
```

The output would render as

```html
<input 
    name="myDate"
    id="myDate"
    type="date"
    required/>
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't really use JSP (and I replied once, then deleted it when I understood the "must by valid XML" thing). The cleanest I can come up with is this:

```
<% if (isDisabled) { %>
  <button name="btn1" disabled="disabled">Hello</button>
<% } else { %>
  <button name="btn1">Hello</button>
<% } %>
```

Comment: As stated in the question, while this will work it's messier than I would like, especially with 15+ attributes in common between the two branches of the if statement.