# jsp : set an attribute of an element based on condition

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

```
<jsp:element name="input">
    <jsp:attribute name="type">radio</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="id">${status.index}${loop.index}</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="name">skillLevel[${status.index}].skillLevelId</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="value">${4 - loop.index}</jsp:attribute>
    <c:if test = "${(4 - loop.index) == skillLevel.getSkillLevelId()}">
        <jsp:attribute name="checked">checked</jsp:attribute>
    </c:if>
</jsp:element>
```

Shows error that c:if tag cant be within jsp:element tag. I just want to add the attribute "checked" for the "input" element based on the test condition.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507610/jsp-can-i-use-jspattribute-inside-cif-exception-must-use-jspbody-to) question?

Comment: @radimpe Yes..I did the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSP - Can I use <jsp:attribute> inside <c:if>? Exception: "Must use jsp:body to specify tag body"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507610/jsp-can-i-use-jspattribute-inside-cif-exception-must-use-jspbody-to)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ?

```
<c:if test = "${(4 - loop.index) == skillLevel.getSkillLevelId()}">
<c:set var="isChecked" value="checked"/>
</c:if>

<jsp:element name="input">
    <jsp:attribute name="type">radio</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="id">${status.index}${loop.index}</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="name">skillLevel[${status.index}].skillLevelId</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="value">${4 - loop.index}</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="${isChecked}">${isChecked}</jsp:attribute>
</jsp:element>
```

Comment: Good try..but it doesnt work. What I get is : <input type = "radio" id = "00" name = "skillLevel[0].skillLevelId" value = "4" ${isChecked}>

Comment: @XavierDSouza Are you getting the same result for both the conditions, passing through `if` and normal flow ?